# Angular material theming receive current theme variable

Tags: angular, variables, sass, angular-material, themes

My question is how I can receive the variable of the current theme in my components scss. I know that I can declare mixins and parse the theme as a parameter to them, but when I do this, my styles would be included globally and not only in my component, because I would have to include the mixins in my main scss in order to parse the current theme to it.

Another option would be to define all my theme variables in a variables file hardcoded and use them depending on the value of my theme service, but here is the problem, that I dont know how to use  typescript inside of sass

Comment: Are you trying to make global `primary`, `accent`, `warn` colors' `classes` to be accessible everywhere with minimal code?

Comment: I only want  the variables globally, in the best case the theme variable directly, in order to select afterwards for example which tone of the primary I want to take for which attribute of my scss class.